# Missing dates when using GROUP BY date

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have `survey_results` table:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_results (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    scores jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone  
);
```

I have the following records in this table:

```
INSERT INTO survey_results (id, scores, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (1, '{"medic": { "social": { "total": "high" } } }', '2018-01-11', '2018-01-10');

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, scores, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (2, '{"medic": { "social": { "total": "high" } } }', '2018-01-12', '2018-01-12');
```

and following query:

```
SELECT
  distinct(date(survey_results.created_at)),

  ROUND(
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (
      scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)
    ) * 1.0 /

    (
      GREATEST(
        COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high','medium','low')
    )
  ) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)), 1.0))* 100, 2
)
 AS positive

  FROM survey_results
  WHERE  
    survey_results.created_at::date >= '2018-01-10'
    AND survey_results.created_at::date <= '2018-01-12'
  GROUP BY date, scores
  ORDER BY date ASC;
```

which returns:

```
date        positive
2018-01-11  100
2018-01-12  100
```

The problem is that query omitted 2018-01-10 because there was not records, that's because of group by. Is there any way to update this query to also return days that do not have records:

```
date        positive
2018-01-10  0
2018-01-11  100
2018-01-12  100
```

Here is sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5e007/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [`generate_series()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)

```
SELECT date::date, coalesce(positive, 0.00) as positive
FROM generate_series('2018-01-10'::date, '2018-01-12', '1d') s(date)
LEFT JOIN (
    -- your query
    SELECT
      distinct(date(survey_results.created_at)),
      ROUND(
        COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (
          scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)
        ) * 1.0 /
        (
          GREATEST(
            COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high','medium','low')
        )
      ) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)), 1.0))* 100, 2
    )
     AS positive
      FROM survey_results
      WHERE  
        survey_results.created_at::date >= '2018-01-10'
        AND survey_results.created_at::date <= '2018-01-12'
      GROUP BY date, scores
    -- your query
    ) q USING(date)
ORDER BY date ASC;

    date    | positive 
------------+----------
 2018-01-10 |     0.00
 2018-01-11 |   100.00
 2018-01-12 |   100.00
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

The date is not "missing". Think of it this way: your query asked the server to return all data WHERE the created_at value is >= '2018-01-10' and created_at value is <= '2018-01-12'. The query is performing correctly.

If you want to contrast a data set against an arbitrary set of dates, then you must generate that set. Some data warehouse practitioners use a Date Dimension for this, which contains all relevant dates, with handy attributes like Fiscal Year, IsHoliday, and the like.

Alternatively, you can generate such sequences yourself, and use those (either as views, derived tables, etc.), and LEFT JOIN the date sequence to your actual query. Then, you can apply your date predicate to the sequence, and any dates lacking data in the outer query will be populated with NULL. You may also elect to transform those columns into some concrete value, such as '' or 0 (zero).

Here is an example query to generate an arbitrary sequence of dates. You can imagine how to modify this to suit your environment. This is for MSSQL 2017, but the idea is the same for any platform.

```
DECLARE @dtStartDate datetime
DECLARE @dtEndDate datetime
SET @dtStartDate = '2018-01-10'
SET @dtEndDate = '2018-01-12'

SELECT
  T.DateVal,
  CASE DATEPART(weekday, T.DateVal)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
  END AS WeekDay,
  DATEPART(day, T.DateVal) AS [Date],
  DATEPART(month, T.DateVal) AS [Month],
  DATEPART(year, T.DateVal) AS [Year]
FROM
(
  SELECT
      DATEADD(day, SEQ.SeqValue, @dtStartDate) DateVal
  FROM
  (
  SELECT
      (HUNDREDS.SeqValue + TENS.SeqValue + ONES.SeqValue) SeqValue
  FROM
      (
      SELECT 0  SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 8 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 9 SeqValue
      ) ONES
  CROSS JOIN
      (
      SELECT 0 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 10 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 20 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 30 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 40 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 50 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 60 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 70 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 80 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 90 SeqValue
      ) TENS
  CROSS JOIN
      (
      SELECT 0 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 100 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 200 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 300 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 400 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 500 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 600 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 700 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 800 SeqValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 900 SeqValue
      ) HUNDREDS
  ) SEQ
) T
WHERE
  T.DateVal <= @dtEndDate
ORDER BY
  T.DateVal ASC
```